# SailsJS app not launching with PM2

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sails.js, pm2

I have a SailsJS Application that works fine if i start it with:

`$ sails lift`

or

`$ sudo nohup node app.js`

but if i try to start it with:

`$ pm2 start app.js -x -- --prod`

it gives an error like this:

`` app-0 (err): ------------------------------------------------------------------------
app-0 (err): Aborted due to warnings.
app-0 (err): Running "clean:dev" (clean) task
app-0 (err): Cleaning .tmp/public...ERROR
app-0 (err): Warning: Unable to delete ".tmp/public" file (EACCES: permission denied, unlink '.tmp/public/base.html'). 
app-0 (err): ------------------------------------------------------------------------
app-0 (err): error: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
app-0 (err): error: Please fix it, then **restart Sails** to continue running tasks (e.g. watching for changes in assets)
app-0 (err): error: Or if you're stuck, check out the troubleshooting tips below.
app-0 (err): error: Troubleshooting tips:
app-0 (err): error: 
app-0 (err): error:  *-> Are "grunt" and related grunt task modules installed locally?  Run `npm install` if you're not sure.
app-0 (err): error: 
app-0 (err): error:  *-> You might have a malformed LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript file, etc.
app-0 (err): error: 
app-0 (err): error:  *-> Or maybe you don't have permissions to access the `.tmp` directory?
app-0 (err): error:      e.g., `/home/anubhav/wishup/opsdashboard-nodejs/.tmp` ?
app-0 (err): error: 
app-0 (err): error:      If you think this might be the case, try running:
app-0 (err): error:      sudo chown -R 1000 /home/anubhav/wishup/opsdashboard-nodejs/.tmp ``

Comment: Can you please try using sudo pm2 start app.js -x -- --prod

Comment: I tried that. Doesn't work.

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that you have problems with permissions... Try changing owner or something. Grunt can't write on .tmp folder...

Answer (score 0):

did you try to :-

```
sudo rm -rf .tmp/public
cd <you project dir >
sudo npm install 
sudo  NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app.js
```